# write always initial value in Prolog programming

Tags: prolog

Assume I made a function like below in swi-prolog.

`function1(param) :- VALUE is 0, findValue(VALUE), write(VALUE).`

However **0** is always printed out. findValue function is logically correct.'

Is it impossible to use **calculated VALUE in function1**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit `VALUE is 0`.

By stating it, the function `findValue` will set the rest of the variables according to `VALUE`, because the claims you provide first are the axiom-level true ones, and the rest correspond to them.

For example, take

```
func(X):- X is 0.
```

If you query `func(X).` it will result in `X=0` because it assumes you want to make an assignment.

However, if you query with a number like `func(0).` it will check if `X==0` or not, resulting in a boolean answer.

Comment: But, interpreter showed error message.
`Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.`

Comment: Probably a problem with your `findValue` method, which you didnt include. Add it.